# Docker unable to access jar file

Tags: java, docker, spring-boot, jar, docker-compose

The docker container is not able to access the jar file, that is being accessed over the mount point `/my/project/dir`.
I am certain it is not a permission issue, because I changed the access rights locally, so it should be able to read/write/execute it.

This is the `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM tomcat:9-jre8
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install librrds-perl rrdtool -y
VOLUME ["/data/rrdtool", "/my/project/dir"]
ENTRYPOINT [ "java","-jar","/my/project/dir/build/libs/spring-project-0.1.0.jar" ]
```

And this is the `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '2'
services:
 db:
   container_name: db1
   image: mysql:8
   restart: always
   environment:
     MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password123
     MYSQL_USER: user123
     MYSQL_PASSWORD: pasw
     MYSQL_DATABASE: mydb
   expose:
     - "3307"
 db2:
   container_name: db2
   image: mysql:8
   restart: always
   environment:
     MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password123
     MYSQL_USER: user123
     MYSQL_PASSWORD: pasw
     MYSQL_DATABASE: mydb2
   expose:
     - "3308"
 spring:
   container_name: spring-boot-project
   build: 
     context: ./
     dockerfile: Dockerfile
   links:
     - db:db1
     - db2:db2
   depends_on:
     - db
     - db2
   expose:
     - "8081"
   ports:
     - "8081:8081"
   restart: always
```

This is the output from `docker-compose logs spring`:

```
Error: Unable to access jarfile /my/project/dir/build/libs/spring-project-0.1.0.jar
```

Comment: This is hard to answer without seeing any error message. Could you run `docker-compose logs spring` and post the output?

Comment: Are you sure you have `build/libs/spring-project-0.1.0.jar` in volume `/my/project/dir`?

Comment: @mbuechmann I added the logs

Comment: @BukharovSergey I am very certain it exists. When I run `java -jar /my/project/dir/build/libs/spring-project-0.1.0.jar` on the local machine the application launches.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't see you copying the `jar` into the container anywhere. You should try moving a `VOLUME` declaration from `Dockerfile` to the `compose` file into the `spring` service  like this:

```
  volumes:
    - /my/project/dir:/app
```

And then inside Dockerfile you should point to the dir:

```
ENTRYPOINT [ "java","-jar","/app/build/libs/spring-project-0.1.0.jar" ]
```

Later on if you'd like to deploy it (for example) you should copy the project files directly into the image instead of utilizing the `volumes` approach. So in `Dockerfile` you'd then do:

```
COPY . /app
```

instead of `VOLUME [..]`

**Putting it all together:**

**development:**

Dockerfile:

```
FROM tomcat:9-jre8
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install librrds-perl rrdtool -y
ENTRYPOINT [ "java","-jar","/app/build/libs/spring-project-0.1.0.jar" ]
```

compose-file:

```
version: '2'
services:
    [..]
    spring:
       container_name: spring-boot-project
       build: .
       links:
         - db:db1
         - db2:db2
       depends_on:
         - db
         - db2
       ports:
         - "8081:8081"
       restart: always
       volumes:
         - /my/project/dir:/app
```

**deployment:**

Dockerfile (that is placed inside project's folder, docker build requires it's build context to be in a current directory):

```
FROM tomcat:9-jre8
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install librrds-perl rrdtool -y
COPY . /app
ENTRYPOINT [ "java","-jar","/app/build/libs/spring-project-0.1.0.jar" ]
```

compose-file:

```
version: '2'
services:
    [..]
    spring:
       container_name: spring-boot-project
       build: .
       links:
         - db:db1
         - db2:db2
       depends_on:
         - db
         - db2
       expose:
         - "8081"
```

Comment: this worked! I was trying to copy it as well but that did not work out. I followed this tutorial https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot-docker/

Comment: I'm writing a edit now making the `COPY` approach more usable as i used a little shortcut stating it.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `Spring-Boot` Project with `Maven` build. Try with below

**Dockerfile**.

```
FROM maven:3.8.4-openjdk-17 as maven-builder
COPY src /app/src
COPY pom.xml /app

RUN mvn -f /app/pom.xml clean package -DskipTests
FROM openjdk:17-alpine

COPY --from=maven-builder app/target/dockube-spring-boot.jar /app-service/dockube-spring-boot.jar
WORKDIR /app-service

EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","dockube-spring-boot.jar"]
```

> dockube-spring-boot.jar // replace with your generated jar name

Here is the [Sample Code Available](https://github.com/Maheshbhusanoor/dockube-spring-boot)