# Docker unable to access jar file without docker-compose

Tags: java, docker, maven

as far as I know I only got [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50216280/docker-unable-to-access-jar-file) answer for my query, but unfortunately I do not have docker-compose.yml I am just trying with plain Dockerfile below is my dockerFile.

```
FROM openjdk:8-jre-alpine
VOLUME /tmp
ARG JAR_FILE
COPY ${JAR_FILE} ebiPorjectJava.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/ebiProjectJava.jar"]
```

but build is getting successful, by below command.

```
docker build -t ebiproject .
```

but when I am trying to run the docker it says unable to access jar file

```
docker run -p 3000:3000 ebiproejct
```

but it says unable to access jar
[image]

I am running docker on windows and I have spring boot application to run

I updated with below one:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jre-alpine
VOLUME /tmp
ARG JAR_FILE
COPY ${JAR_FILE} /ebiProjectJava.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/ebiProjectJava.jar"]
```

but now I am getting corrupted error:
[image]

Comment: Could you problem be as simple as a typo? `COPY ${JAR_FILE} ` **ebiPorjectJava** `.jar` vs `ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","` **/ebiProjectJava.jar** `"]`

Comment: updated ENTRYPOINT but still same issue I am seeing unable to access jarfile **ebiProjectJava.jar** without /

Comment: oops I literally ad typo, but now getting courrpted error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ARG JAR_FILE

expects you to pass the path of the jar_file as docker run argument

Otherwise nothing will be copied to the place, thus java jar won't be able to run the jar.

Check this out: https://vsupalov.com/docker-env-vars/

Comment: what you are suggesting hard code jar file path to pass?

Comment: sorry I am totally new to docker so not sure if I followed

Comment: got that point I supposed to do ARG JAR_FILE=target/*.jar

Comment: No need for apologizes. 
Have you solved it?

Answer (score 0):

In this situation you can go in your container with this command:

```
docker run --rm -it <container_name> <image_name> <command>
```

you can use `bash`, `ash` or `sh` as

and after entering the container, you can check, run, or any tests in that.